# What's this cuboid at rqt_graph?

Tags: ros, rqt-graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use robot arm(Ufactory Lite6), and I got rqt_graph.

In the graph, nodes are showed by ellipses and topics are showed by rectangle. However, there are cuboid among them.

what is this cuboid? Please tell me.

At nodes only mode, we can watch "/ufactory/lite6_traj_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/status&goal (rectangle)".
At nodes and topics(All) mode, we can watch "/ufactory/lite6_traj_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/action_topics (cuboid)", not "status&goal".

What is the relationship between "status&goal"and "action_topics"? Please tell me.

Nodes only mode.
[image: image description]

Node and topics(All) mode.
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409743/what%27s-this-cuboid-at-rqt_graph?/) by [Renox](https://answers.ros.org/users/106378/renox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2022-11-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-11-23**:
Pedantic perhaps, but a *cuboid* is 3D. `rqt_graph` is pretty fancy, but it's not a 3D program (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An ActionServer/ActionClient communicate with each other using 5 ros topics with specific names: cancel, feedback, goal, result, status.

That box is removing clutter from the diagram by not explicitly listing these 5 well-known topic names.

See http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib for a poorly-written description of actionlib.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Renox](https://answers.ros.org/users/106378/renox/) on 2022-11-23**:
Thank you for your reply. I understood.